# How to select the specific position element in the certain class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is my part of HTML code:

```
<label>
    Work&nbsp;Address:
</label>
<input type="text" id="workAddress0" name="workAddress0">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-small" onclick="ui.createTextfield('work')"><br>

<label>
    Hobby&nbsp;Address:
</label>
<input type="text" id="hobbyAddress0" name="hobbyAddress0">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-small" onclick="ui.createTextfield('hobby')"><br>
```

My CSS is:

```
.btn.btn-small:first-of-type{ 
position: absolute;
left: 953px;
top:290px;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
}

.btn.btn-small:nth-of-type(2){ 
position: absolute;
left: 953px;
top:337px;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
```

I want to set the first button to the top 290px and second button to top 337px; But this select doesn't work. Could you tell me how to realize that ? I want to select the first and the second of this class(btn btn-small) separately. Thank you in advance

Comment: may be you have problem due to position:absolute; http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:first-of-type will look here for first appearance of a tag, here  input or label and will select it if it has also the class . here your first-of-type input has no class at all, it will never be selected.

You can try to use the ~ selector to jump class to class.

```css
.btn.btn-small {
  position: absolute;
  left: 953px;
  top: 290px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn.btn-small ~.btn.btn-small {
  position: absolute;
  left: 953px;
  top: 337px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn.btn-small ~.btn.btn-small ~ .btn.btn-small {
  top: auto;/* reset here , else third, forth will be at 337px; */
}
```

```html
<label>
  Work&nbsp;Address:
</label>
<input type="text" id="workAddress0" name="workAddress0">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-small" onclick="ui.createTextfield('work')">
<br>

<label>
  Hobby&nbsp;Address:
</label>
<input type="text" id="hobbyAddress0" name="hobbyAddress0">
<input type="button" value="+" class="btn btn-small" onclick="ui.createTextfield('hobby')">
<br>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `-of-type` selectors in CSS refer to the element type (i.e. p, a, div, etc.), not the class.

You could use a selector like this to target the first button:

```
#workAddress0 + .btn {
   ...
}
```

In plain English, this selector reads as:

> find an element with class including "btn" that immediately follows an element
>   with id "workAddress0"